# Word for someone who sticks up for others, even those whom he/she doesn’t know, expecting nothing in return

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word in English for someone who would go out of their way to help those whom he/she doesn’t even know, join fights that are not his in order to help others who can’t defend themselves, and take his/her friends’ problems seriously as if they were his own?

Comment: Perhaps even: Knight in shining armour, guardian-angel - depending on the usage.

Comment: Perhaps *upstanding*.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/selfless

**Selfless person** - Being selfless is similar to being altruistic — another word for giving to others without looking for personal gain. If you give time, money, or things to other people without expecting something in return, that's selfless.

humanitarian

good samaritan

helping hand